# Can I use blender for creating a 3D integrated scene?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is blender good for compositing? I want to integrate my models in to real life footage and am expecting realistic results. Or can I make a 3D characters-integrated-real-life-scene which will look decent and professional?

Comment: Hello :). Decent and professional look depends more on your skill, than your software...

Comment: Hi :) You can look at blender.org at see [real world uses](https://www.blender.org/about/user-stories/) and see for yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

While Blender's compositing interface isn't as well designed as, say, Blackmagic Fusion, it is absolutely capable of realistically integrating CGI content into real life footage.

However (maybe you know this, but I'll say it anyway, because it can never be stressed enough), nothing is magic; it takes skill.  For any CGI-video integration to be convincing (regardless of the software being used), the CGI content has to be rendered well with at least near-photorealism, and has to match the video in terms of lighting, focal length, and motion to name a few aspects, and within the compositor you have to work with the rendered animation to make its dynamic range, color grading, etc, also match the footage.  You can find a wealth of great tutorials on YouTube for how to do these things well.

All that to say, go ahead and practice working with the compositor!  If it doesn't look convincing, don't despair; chances are, some things about the render may need to be improved, or the color grading.  In the long run, the skill is what brings a product across the finish line, not the software.

Comment: Sorry if my question is a bit stupid! Im new to blender! Not only blender, to this whole 3D magic! Just started a few weeks ago with blender! Made some models and sculptures! I felt like i should carry on with this! But I am a bit impatient, I thought of having my models properly made and textured and probably integrated in a cool video! I searched on youtube for tutorials, found out most of the results of the tutorials arent very good! And they only work on one still frame image, I got a bit nervous if blender is limited to in video and films stuff!  Now I understand it's all about skills!

Comment: @AbdullahAlSayed do you know this tutorial? https://youtu.be/hymtATx1QXw (Add CGI Characters to Live Footage | Blender 2.8 VFX Tutorial by CG Geek)